# sigaction, implicit declaration

Tags: c, signals, sigaction

I am trying to catch signals in c and ignore them for the parent process while the child handles them normally. I currently have:

```
   #include<signal.h>
   #include<bits/sigaction.h>

   int main(){
     struct sigaction parentsig, childsig;
     parentsig.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
     sigaction(SIGINT, &parentsig, &childsig);
     return 0;
   }
```

I am currently compiling it with `gcc -std=c99 -o smallsh smallsh.c`, but I get the error `implicit declaration of function ‘sigaction’`. After some debugging I found out that it has to do with `sigaction(SIGINT, &parentsig, &childsig)` line. Every example that I can find has something similar to this since it sets what struct to follow when handling signals. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong with this?

Comment: Please show an [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sounds like you have just left out `#include <signal.h>` but can't say for sure without an MCVE.

Comment: Sorry, I have included <signal.h> and <bits/sigaction.h>. It does not through any errors or warning if I eliminate `sigation(SIGNINT, &parentsig, &childsig);`

Comment: Please show an MCVE. There is no way we can tell you what the problem is with the information provided.

Comment: Remove `#include<bits/sigaction.h>`.

Comment: When I remove `#include<bits/sigation.h>`, I get `storage size of ‘parentsig’ isn’t known` and `storage size of ‘childsig’ isn’t known` errors along with the one I was getting before.

Comment: Sorry I missed the `c99` part of your compile line. My understanding is that `sigaction` does not conform to c99. You need to take that out or use `signal` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: @kaylum: `sigaction()` is POSIX. The c-standard version is irrelevant.